# Changing column data from string to datetime data format in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any advice on how to change a date time value in a large table with many rows.

the current datatype is in string format and looks like this in the rows:

```
23/03/2022 00:00:00
23/03/2022 00:00:00
23/03/2022 00:00:00
23/03/2022 00:00:00
23/03/2022 00:00:00
23/03/2022 00:00:00
```

I have tried convert

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(7),[start_date] )
   FROM 'table_name'
```

would like to change this to a datetime format, any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Date and time data types don't have a format; the format of the value is determined by the presentation layer *not* the SQL Layer. If you don't know how to change the displayed format in the application your creating, then *that* is what you should be asking about.

Comment: If, however, you are storing date and time data as a string based data type (`(n)(var)char`) then you have a design flaw and should be fixing your design to store the data in an appropriate date and time data type.

Comment: I would add a new column, then fill it with values (update table set new_col = convert(datetime2(7), old_column), then drop old column

Comment: You'll need `UPDATE dbo.table SET new_col = CONVERT(datetime2(7), old_col, 103);`. The `103` is important as it tells SQL Server to interpret it as d/m/y regardless of your language / dateformat settings. I don't think there is going to be a _reliable_ way to convert the existing column to the new type without some kind of transfer, because you can't say `ALTER COLUMN <newtype, style number>`. Hopefully this is a good lesson in storing data in the right data type in the first place.

Comment: @AaronBertrand you are totally right that it's unreliable, because there's no telling what junk strings are in the column beforehand, but if they can be successfully converted to a proper format with `update table_name set start_date = convert(varchar(19), convert(datetime, start_date, 103), 126);` then you could actually do an in-place column conversion with `alter table table_name alter column start_date datetime;`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Right, I meant _in a single step_ (what you're suggesting I'd still qualify as a "transfer" first, but using a second column is safer because you don't risk losing any of the original data). And even _that_ is only reliable if all the dates are in fact in d/m/y and they're all valid dates.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid potential data loss (or almost certain failure) trying to update the column's data type directly, here is my suggestion:

1. Add a new column:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.table_name
     ADD some_new_column datetime2(7) NULL;
   ```
2. Try to update that column:

   ```
   UPDATE dbo.table_name 
     SET some_new_column = TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(7), 
       original_column, 103) -- important for d/m/y
     WHERE original_column IS NOT NULL;
   ```
3. Identify any rows where the original value couldn't be converted (and fix them, depending on what you find):

   ```
   SELECT original_column
     FROM dbo.table_name
     WHERE original_column IS NOT NULL
       AND some_new_column IS NULL;
   ```
4. Once all the data is fixed, drop the original column and rename the new one to the old name:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.table_name DROP COLUMN original_column;

   EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.table_namesome_new_column',
        N'original_column', N'COLUMN';
   ```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=236335bc1be38d4a5a7ab69064e4f7cd)

Repeat this process for any column where you are storing dates as strings (and in the future make sure to use the right data types from the start). More reading:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)
- [How much impact can a data type choice have?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/data-type-choice)
- [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org)